# How to fix Django web app which is displaying a wrong css layout for Admin site

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm developing a Django web app. If I try to access to the admin site there is a new button for selecting theme color. This button is not displayed properly. Here a screenshot:

[image]

I didn't add any third party plugin about admin themes and I don't know which part of code you need to investigate the problem. Here you can find the installed packages of my python virtual env:

```
asgiref==3.6.0
autopep8==2.0.2
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
black==23.3.0
certifi==2022.12.7 
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
defusedxml==0.7.1
diff-match-patch==20200713
Django==4.2
django-address==0.2.8
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
django-filter==22.1
django-import-export==3.0.2
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
idna==3.4
MarkupPy==1.14 
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
numpy==1.23.5
odfpy==1.4.1
openpyxl==3.0.10
packaging==23.1
pandas==1.5.1
pathspec==0.11.1
platformdirs==3.5.0
psycopg2==2.9.5
psycopg2-binary==2.9.5
pycodestyle==2.10.0
PySimpleGUI==4.60.4
python-dateutil==2.8.2 
python-decouple==3.8
pytz==2022.6
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.29.0
scipy==1.9.3
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
sqlparse==0.4.3
tablib==3.3.0
tzdata==2022.6
urllib3==1.26.15
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter==3.1.0
xlwt==1.3.0
```

Here you can find my settings.py without sensitive data:

```
    """
Django settings for warehouseproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from decouple import config, AutoConfig
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


config = AutoConfig(search_path=".env")
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "warehouse_app.apps.WarehouseAppConfig",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "crispy_forms",
    "django_filters",
    "import_export",
]

CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap4"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "warehouseproject.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "warehouseproject.wsgi.application"


MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger',
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "it-it"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ('static',)

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

# CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None

LOGIN_URL = "/accounts/login/"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy("device_list")
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%d/%m/%Y", "%d-%m-%Y", "%Y-%m-%d"]

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ["%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"]
```

Here you can find the output from Visual Studio Code Terminal when I try to access the /admin page:

```
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4079
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 20344
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2619
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 958
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18854
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 200 423
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3763
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[02/Jun/2023 16:34:14] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[02/Jun/2023 16:35:35] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[02/Jun/2023 16:35:35] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4079
```

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: The cause of the error may be stated in the terminal editor, if Visual Studio Code (or anything) is used, the error will be displayed in the lower part of the terminal (when you open the admin page in the browser).

Comment: I do not. The question was brought to my attention due to the Bootstrap tag, but it seems to have little to do with Bootstrap. I don't know Django.

Comment: @ali I added the Visual Studio code terminal response of /admin page.

Answer (score 0):

If your Django admin site looks distorted, this typically means that static files are not being served properly. The Django admin interface relies on CSS for styling, and if the CSS files are not loaded correctly, the page would appear distorted.

The first thing to ensure is that you've set `DEBUG = True` in your settings file (`settings.py`). When `DEBUG` is `True`, Django will automatically serve static files like CSS and JavaScript required for the admin site.

However, if `DEBUG` is `False` or you're in a production environment, you need to configure your server to serve static files, as Django does not do it automatically.

When DEBUG is set to False, Django will not automatically serve static files. You'll have to set up static file serving yourself.

In a production environment, it's considered a best practice to have a dedicated web server like Nginx or a cloud service like Amazon S3 to serve static files.

Answer (score 0):

Running `python manage.py collectstatic` worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi. I have already done it but it's not working, admin site still looks distorted.